# Java Cipher setting specific nonce is not workig

Tags: java, authentication, encryption, cryptography, nonce

I need to encrypt parameters in a POST request (in order to exchange an authentication token).
So far so good with PHP I can do it and the request is successful. Below you have the PHP encryption script (PHP code cannot be modified).

```
<?php
    $shared_secret = "dummy_secret";
    // Genere user Json
    $userJson = json_encode(array(
        "external_id" => "30123134", //Required
        "email" => "jperez@gmail.com",
        "name" => "Jose",
        "lastname" => "Perez"
    ));
    // Generate nonce (initialization vector)
    $nonce = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC) ,MCRYPT_RAND);
    // Encrypt user Json to generate the encrypted form
    $encryptedForm =mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $shared_secret, $userJson, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $nonce);
    // Encode the encrypted form and the nonce
    $encryptedForm = base64_encode($encryptedForm);
    $nonce = base64_encode($nonce);
    $body = json_encode(array("encryptedform" => $encryptedForm, "nonce" => $nonce));
?>
```

Now I'm trying to do the same with Java. Unfortunately there must be something wrong with my implementation, because the POST request returns 401  (unauthorized).

```
public static EncryptedData encrypt(String plainText, String key) throws Exception {       
    // Generating IV.
    byte[] iv = new byte[IV_SIZE];
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    random.nextBytes(iv);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(random.getSeed(IV_SIZE));        

    // Encrypt.
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES"), ivParameterSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());

    // Base64 encoding.
    String nonce = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(ivParameterSpec.getIV());       
    String encryptedFrom = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encrypted);        

    EncryptedData data = new EncryptedData(nonce, encryptedFrom);

    return data;
}
```

What's wrong with the java version?

Comment: mcrypt doesn't support PKCS5 Padding.  Try turning it off in your Java code.

Comment: It also zero pads the key to 16 bytes. `mcrypt` sucks, convert your code and never look back. For now you'd probably best expand your "secret" to 16 bytes.  Note that you should try and *decrypt* the PHP generated ciphertext. With a random IV you can try until the universe ends to get the same ciphertext.

Comment: Does the nonce generated in Java (IvParameterSpec) follows the same guidelines of the nonce generated in PHP? Are both exchangeable?

Comment: CBC doesn't use a nonce, it uses an IV which bits should be unpredictable to an attacker. And yes, other than the usual BS of mcrypt which may pad or crop the IV value, it should act the same. Again, mcrypt sucks, and making a compatible implemention will be hard. Better pad the plaintext with zeros yourself as e.g. BouncyCastle's zeropadding is not compatible either.

Comment: Thanks, finally I found a solution detailed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this puzzle, fortunately I could translate that php code into a java equivalent:

```
public static ar.edu.ues21.menu.util.EncryptedData encrypt2(String key, String data) throws Exception {
    ar.edu.ues21.menu.util.EncryptedData result =  null;
    BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(128)), new ZeroBytePadding());

    byte[] iv = new byte[16];        
    SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").nextBytes(iv);

    CipherParameters ivAndKey = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key.getBytes("UTF-8")), iv);        
    cipher.init(true, ivAndKey);

    byte[] input = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];

    int cipherLength = cipher.processBytes(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
    cipher.doFinal(cipherText, cipherLength);

    result = new ar.edu.ues21.menu.util.EncryptedData(Base64.encodeBase64String(iv), Base64.encodeBase64String(cipherText));
    return result;
}
```

But I was lucky, the real problem was the target API does not have any documentation regarding to the kind of encryption needed for the token generation.